# Is there a compact way to define dependent variables in ansible?

Tags: ansible

I have a number of variables I'd like to set (for DRY reasons) in an ansible playbook. Each of these variables is dependent on an earlier variable. The following is a simple example with two variables, but in my real situation there are more:

```
- set_fact:
    current_user: "{{ lookup('env', 'USER') }}"

- set_fact:
    repository_root: /home/{{ current_user }}/code/devops
```

With more variables, it is a bit verbose to repeat the `set_fact:` line for each variable. Unfortunately, if I merge them into the following:

```
- set_fact:
    current_user: "{{ lookup('env', 'USER') }}"
    repository_root: /home/{{ current_user }}/code/devops
```

`current_user` is not defined at the time `repository_root`'s expression is evaluated and it fails.

Is there a more succinct way to express many variables dependent on previous variables within a playbook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you need `set_fact` in this case?

You can define this variables in inventory or play vars:

```
current_user: "{{ lookup('env', 'USER') }}"
repository_root: /home/{{ current_user }}/code/devops
```

They will be evaluated (and chained, if required) only when used.

Comment: I hadn't thought of putting them in play variables, that may be a good idea.

Comment: This does indeed work with my pattern of use. I wonder if they were used in an order different than they were defined, if it would evaluate as necessary or just choke. Oh, well. That would belong in another question. Thank you.